# nest if statement in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. I need add a nest if statement in recrod selection formula

The original one like this

```
    if {?Company}<>0 then  {HQCO.HQCo}={?Company} else 1=1 and
    if {?Job}<>'zzzzz' then {udJobEmp.Job}={?Job} else 1=1 and 
    if {?Employee}<>0 then {udJobEmp.Employee}={?Employee} else 1=1
```

but i need use nest if statement, i try to do something like this but it is not right.

```
if ({?Company}<>0 then if 
  ({?Job}<>'zzzzz' then if
    ( {?Employee}<>0 then {udJobEmp.Employee}={?Employee} then  {udJobEmp.Job}={?Job}  then      {HQCO.HQCo}={?Company} else 1=1)else 1=1)else1=1)
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I try and avoid using if's in selection formula. Try something more like:

```
({?Company}=0 or {HQCO.HQCo}={?Company}) and
({?Job}='zzzzz' or {udJobEmp.Job}={?Job}) and 
({?Employee}=0 or {udJobEmp.Employee}={?Employee})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your logic correct, but this is how you would approach this whole thing:

```
if ({?Company}<>0) AND ({?Job}<>'zzzzz') AND ({?Employee}<>0) THEN 
({udJobEmp.Employee}={?Employee}) AND ({HQCO.HQCo}={?Company}) ELSE
1 = 1
```

Hope this helps,

Chris